# change image of UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Somebody know whats the way to change the background image of the minus button of UITable cell,

[image]

I need to change this button [image] to something like [image]

because if you change between iOS6 and iOS7 this button changed.

Comment: posted answer @user2720097

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
    {
        [super willTransitionToState:state];
        if ((state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)
        {
            for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
            {
                if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl"])
                {
                    UIImageView *deleteBtn = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 33)];
                    [deleteBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deleteNewImg.png"]];
                    [[subview.subviews objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:deleteBtn];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```